# Как записать Map<File, Integer> в .txt Java

Tags: java

Есть метод, который выводит промежуточные значения:

```
  public void  IntermediateResultWrite(Map<File, Integer> hm){
    Set<Map.Entry<File, Integer>> set = hm.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<File, Integer> me : set) {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":"+me.getKey() + ": ");
            System.out.println(me.getValue());
        }
```

Мне надо промежуточные значения записать в .txt.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос те поисковые запросы которые не дали вам нужную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<File, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new File("somefile1"), 1);
map.put(new File("somefile2"), 2);

try ( PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("/path/to/output.txt")) ) {
    for ( Map.Entry<File, Integer> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
        writer.write(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Если нужно писать в файл который является ключом мапы, уберите try-with-resource внутрь цикла.